# disable Javascript auto suggest function for some word

Tags: javascript, jquery

I has only one question about JavaScript. can we disable auto suggest function for only certain word? I mean, if User typing some word such as "plate" then auto suggest function will not return any value but if they typing other than that, the function will work as it mean to.

Comment: depends what auto suggest you are using

Comment: are you using jquery autocomplete? Show code please

Comment: @teovankot i only just want to know either the method is exist or not, i doesn't have any coding because the project is still in brainstorm stage.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an event listener added to your textbox like following:

```
 $('#mytextbox').keyup(function(e){
    if ($(this).val().match(/^plate$/))
    {
      return;

    }
    // proceed your autocomplete here
 });
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.